# Javascript callback from string variable doesn't work, tried normal solutions

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have read the relative questions here which they propose to use something like:

```
var functionName="myFunctionName";
window[functionName]();
```

Well here i am but it doesn't work:

Custom modal box function that has a callback string variable:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //
            // Events
            //
            $('#btnStep1').click(function () {
                ylaConfirm('message', 'title', 'Y', 'N', 'doStep1');
            });
            //
            //
            // Functions
            //
            function doStep1() {
                ...
                ...
                });
            }
            function ylaConfirm(_msg, _title, _btnYes, _btnNo, _callbackYes) {
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: _msg,
                    title: _title,
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: _btnYes,
                            className: "btn-success",
                            callback: function () {
                                window[_callbackYes]();
                            }
                        },
                        main: {
                            label: _btnNo,
                            className: "btn-primary"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //


    </script>
```

Firebug reports: not defined...

Calling Code:

```
ylaConfirm('message', 'title', 'Y', 'N', 'doStep1');
```

ideas?

Comment: If _callbackYes is a function, just call it. Please show your calling code too.

Comment: try just entering _callbackYes in Firebug console. What does it return?

Comment: Added calling method. @SmokeyPHP i tried this but the same error.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Right now it is inside of this JSON object, what happens if you do `window[_callbackYes]();` right in the first line of `ylaConfirm()`?

Comment: @funkwurm: if i put it in the first line i still get "TypeError: window[_callbackYes] is not a function"

Comment: Is `doStep1()` namespaced? If so, you'll have to call this using the proper namespace. Can you give us some context as to where it is defined?

Comment: i dont think it is. It is just a function a script tag in an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: Ah, see, now we're one step closer to the problem, does `doStep1()` exist and if so in which scope/namespace. Could you add the code of and around `function doStep1()` to the question?

Comment: i added in the question all the code without the actual implementation of doStep1

Comment: why don't you pass the function to ylaConfirm instead of a function name string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things.

```
ylaConfirm('message', 'title', 'Y', 'N', 'doStep1');
```

1. When the `window[_callbackYes]();` is executed, `doStep1` is not yet defined. So you can define it before `click` function.
2. The other way to fix this problem is to defined `doStep1` as an inline anonymous function and calling it directly as `_callbackYes()` instead of `window[_callbackYes]();`. So, `ylaConfirm` call will become like this

   ```
   ylaConfirm('message', 'title', 'Y', 'N', function(){
       //Include the actual definition of doStep1 here.
   });
   ```
3. As mentioned by @VoronoiPotato in the comments, you can pass the function directly as the third parameter (either you should move the definition of `doStep1` before `click` or define `doStep1` like this `var doStep1 = function() {..}`).

   ```
   ylaConfirm('message', 'title', 'Y', 'N', doStep1);
   ...
   ...
   _callbackYes(); // Instead of window[_callbackYes]();
   ```

Comment: yes yes yes, pass the function! You don't even have to make it anonymous if you don't want you can use var doStep1 = function(){};

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Included the changes you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: hooray! glad we could find you a sensible solution earthdog

Comment: I doubt the 3rd solution will work because it seems `ylaConfirm()` is called outside of the `$(document).ready(function())` scope and therefor it wouldn't be able to find `doStep1()`.

Comment: guys what i did is that i moved ALL functions outside document.ready and it worked...Do i have to read about scope? :)

Comment: I believe `ylaConfirm` is defined outside, but called inside the `$(document).ready`

Comment: @e4rthdog You would have defined `doStep1` before the `click` function, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd advice you to read about what _scope_ is in JavaScript (sometimes called _namespace_ by `C#` programmers) :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: now everything is defined outside document.ready. Inside are only event handlers and standard function calls.

Comment: Javascript is lexically scoped, that means anything outside a function  and declared before the function bleeds in, anything inside of a function is not accessible from outside said function.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe indicates that `window[_callbackYes]` is not defined during the execution of `ylaConfirm`, but is defined by the time the `Yes` button is clicked.

Move definition of `doStep1`

```
function doStep1() {
  ...
}
```

before

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the call

```
window[_callbackYes]();
```

is completely ok. The problem is the scope of `doStep1()`. Defined inside the anonymous ready function, it is not attached to the window object and only callable inside the outer function. Further reference can be found here: [Functions and Function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures)

My suggestion: Either define `doStep1()` outside the ready function or attach it to the window object like this:

```
window.doStep1 = function() {
//do stuff
}
```

This could be necessary if you need the page to be initialized for the function definition (which is highly unlikely I think)